# What's a good job title for one who has worn all the hats at a software start-up?

Tags: resume, startup, title

I recently left my job and I'm trying to figure out what title to put on my resume. I was somewhat of the technical co-founder, but not officially so.

As a lot of folks who have worked in startups know, you don't really do as you're asked, you do as is necessary.

These roles include, but are not limited to:

- Front-end design
- Back-end design
- Deciphering legacy systems
- Product design
- Product architecture
- Selecting software stacks
- Developing documentation, terminology
- Unit testing, release engineering
- Supporting the sales team
- Supporting the clients directly for technical issues
- Hiring staff, training staff, managing staff
- Designing databases
- Project management
- Working with third party vendors for integration
- DevOps

Etc, etc.

I can't really think of a title other than "4-year start-up survivor." What can folks like me call ourselves?

Comment: Full-Stack Software Engineer

Comment: @LawrenceAiello But that doesn't include any of the other roles. If I was just programming I would call it that. I was thinking of "Full-Stack Engineer and Project Manager" but that's a bit long-winded

Comment: "Senior Software Architect" would do fine for Germany I assume.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694). "Questions that address only a specific company **or position** are of limited use to future visitors."

Comment: @DavidK You're right. I'll edit it to be more universal to other "start-up survivors," although the downvotes have already arrived.

Comment: "4-year start-up survivor" sounds fine to me!

Comment: "Utility infielder"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar experience. I worked for a single company for 10 years+, starting in an office of ten people and leaving a company of 10,000+, and had a similarly varied experience. The problem is recruiters and hiring managers want to put you in a box but when you have such varied experiences, boxes can be limiting. If someone cannot understand that you can have a variety of skills, it says more about that person than it does you but I digress.

I found the key is to **pick a title that emphasizes the experience the hiring manager is looking for**. If you are going for a senior developer, development lead or architect role, I would go for "Senior Principal Software Architect". The architect title is sufficiently nebulous to cover a variety of skills. Everything sounds better with the "Senior Principal" prefix but dial it back to "Senior" if you feel that is over the top. Emphasize your design, development, mentoring/training, support and reverse engineering experience.

If you are going for a consulting role or a mix of development and infrastructure, go "Senior Principal Technical Architect" or "Senior Principal DevOps". Emphasize the cloud server infrastructure work, vendor interaction, client interactions and support along with a summary of the architect points above.

If you are going into management, say "Head of Development" (with permission from the co-founder and your development peer). Emphasize your client and vendor interaction, hiring and managing other employees, prioritization and roll out plans. Do not deny your development experience but focus on the tasks a manager needs, e.g. planning, evaluating employees, juggling priorities.

If you are going into another startup role, I would seriously consider using "4-year start-up survivor". If someone is starting a new company, they need someone that can handle multiple, simultaneous roles under pressure. It sounds like you have achieved that. The only downside is larger companies may be biased toward startups, thinking that you are undisciplined, cannot work in a large team or will leave for your own startup as soon as you have sufficient savings.

If you need a single title across multiple CVs, consider the "Senior Principal Technical Architect". It sounds senior but is sufficiently vague to prompt people to ask more about the role, meaning you can sell your wider experience and hopefully create your own box.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question should be along the lines of **how** to select a title and not just what the title should be.

Focus on why you were hired. I worked as a programmer and changed a light bulb one day, but no one called me the electrician (Someone may have as a joke.).

The other thing I would focus on would be what job do you want. If you want to be a programmer, then say you were the programmer. Some companies like people who have a specific skill set and others will like the fact that you're willing to do what is needed. You don't need to itemize everything you did.

Eliminate things you were not that good at and don't want to do. You don't want to be hired for the wrong reasons or get stuck doing things you don't like. You can vary easily get tracked into a particular path in many companies with no way to get out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [akton's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/42057/9080), but I would like to add that job titles aren't universal. I mean, they do not directly correlate to what you are actually doing and what you *think* a job title means at company A may not be the same as what the role does at company B and you don't want to hinder your job prospects by boxing yourself into a role that may not mean the same thing everywhere.

This is especially true of knowledge workers (not so much so of strict management, where titles are long established and quite formal - sometimes, even controlled by a regulator).

Thus, I would not concentrate too much on the job title itself; concentrate rather on your experience and as others have mentioned - you need to tailor your resume to the job you are trying to apply for (there is no one universal resume).

I have also seen resume's where someone with experience like yourself has given their title as "Employee Number 2" or similar (highlighting that they have been there from the start and have worn many hats).

Above all else, avoid the temptation of coming up with a job title for yourself - this might end up firing back at you due to the negative connotations attached to such "self serving" job titles. I'm talking about things like "Code Ninja", "Growth Hacker", and my personal favorite - "Social Media Enabler".

Here are [some other tips](https://econsultancy.com/blog/61819-10-job-titles-to-avoid-in-2013/) on titles to avoid.

In the end, concentrate on your experience.